# Groovy DSL getting anonymous String assignments

Tags: groovy, dsl

I have a DSL that looks like this:

```
aMethod {
    "a name"
    "another name"
    "and a third name"
}
```

My Problem is that I'm unable to access the three string, because calling the closure only returns the last statement. I tried to override the constructor of String(char[] value) which is called when an anonymous String-statement occurs:

```
def original

// primitive way to get the String(char[])-constructor
String.class.constructors.each {
    if(it.toString() == "public java.lang.String(char[])") {
        original = it
    }
}
// overriding the constructor
String.metaClass.constructor = {  char[] value ->
    def instance = original.newInstance(value)
    // ... do some further stuff with the instance ...
    println "Created ${instance}"
    instance
}
// teststring to call String(char[] value)
"teststring"
```

Unfortunately it didn't work and I thought anyway that it is quite complicated.

Comment: I doubt this works without some ASTs. Can you change the DSL? Passing the string as an argument to a method call can solve this, or don't treat them as string, but as pure code: `aMethod { a name }`

Comment: +1 I think you'll need an ast

Comment: I tried the solution with pure code, but in the closure I also allow method calls with String-params, like that: aMethod {forView(another name)}. this pattern is not allowed I think and I didn't want to mix it up. Nevermind, I thought there is an obvious solution like wrapping every statement of a closure with a method

Comment: The strings can be anything? If they are a well-defined set, you can write a class with those strings as methods, and just call them inside the closure.

Comment: no they are not defined

Comment: I see. Can `aMethod{forView(another name)}` be changed to `aMethod{forView another name}`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. Actually it would be great to define everything without quotes. But: After having a dsl that can be translated to java objects I'd loved to have additional annotations in my language at development time. I want to annotate duplicate names and so on. The IDE's I know better, Intellij and Eclipse handle Strings "a name" as one PSI-Elements. Splitting these elements can be very inconvinient ... I guess. I think statements in a closure like aMethod {a name} would result in an interpretation like aMethod {a.name}. That would mean that instead of having a StringLiteral Psi "a name", I would have an Object-Psi and a MethodCall-Psi or something like that. I don't know, and my next goal is just "parsing/creating" my java objects. Are you sure that it is impossible to override the String-Constructor?

Is any constructor called when you have a groovy script with this content:

```
"hello World"
```